# Android - Refactoring value

Tags: java, android, refactoring

I have the following problem:
I use in all my app, which contains many Activities and Fragments, a static byte[] from the main activity that I called MA.bytearray (where MA is the name of the Activity). Well the problem is that when I pause my app and resume it, the value is null, in my opinion is very normal because of Activities live-cycle. So, I decided to make a Class with this static byte[] which acts like a DataBase BUT I used too many times MA.bytearray in my app. Is there a way to refactor the reference from MA.bytearray to DB.bytearray ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IDE are you using, This can be done in Android studio, not sure about Eclipse.
Anyway If you have a static value, it doesn't get affected in activity life cycle, it depends on the class itself, as long as it was used at least one, it will stay in the memory till the process is killed.
I guess is that somewhere in the activity you reinitialize the value with out checking if it was already set, so you overwrite it, try to find where that problem is.
Also this is exactly why it is consider bad to use static values, I'll suggest for you instead is to use a public, not static, parameter inside a class which extends Application, add inside your manifest add: `android:name=".MyApplication"` tag under the application tab with the relevant class name, and whenever you need to get access to that value use `(MyApplication)getApplication()` to get the application instance to access the public variable.

Comment: How can you do it in Android Studio?

Comment: when you change a value name it asks if you want to have a scan over the entire project to change any references as well or it does it by default

Comment: Yes but I want to change the class not the name of the byte array

Comment: Use ctrl + shift + R it will give you the option to scan the whole project for a string and replace it with another string

Answer (score 0):

First write this:

```
class MA ... {
    static byte[] bytearray = DB.bytearray;
}
```

Then inline MA.bytearray field, using your IDE refactoring tools.

Comment: This will do what I want? I don't understand how

Comment: I want my bytearray to depend on DB not on MA at all.

Comment: I am suggesting you a way to do the refactoring. Or else I haven't understood at all what you wanted to do.